# Fix the XSS issues in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, xss

In my organization, we have fortify scan for applications for compliance. in a report I observed that it shows XSS issues in JSP for one variable multiple times. It shows issues when one String variable is getting populated from request and then at other places in javascript functions where that variable is used.
Please find below example.

```
    <%
String gotoNextPoint = request.getParameter("nextPoint");
// issue is reported in with this line
%>
```

in a javascript function

```
    function doCloseTheForm() {
 var nextPoint = "<%=gotoNextPoint%>";
// issue is shown here as well
}
```

So, My question here is, If we encode value for "gotoNextPoint" variable in the scriplet itself, will it work for other places where that variable is getting used? or we have to encode value for "gotoNextPoint" variable at each place where it has been used?

Thanks,

Jay

Comment: The encoding needs to be done where the variable is used in a way that's appropriate to the context. If you're dropping the value into JavaScript, it has to be encoded for JavaScript (probably via a JSON encoder). If it's going into HTML, it should be sanitized for HTML. There's no single encoding that works for both.

Comment: @Pointy I am using that.. means If that variable is used in javascript then I am using encodeForJavaScript(), if it is used to set value in html I am using encodeForHTMLAttribute() functions. My question here is, If I encode value with either encodeForJavaScript() or encodeForHTMLAttribute()  at only one place where it's value is getting populated from request param will work or I have to encode it's value at each and every place?

Comment: If you encode the value for some context, and you save the encoded version, it can be re-used *in that context*.